# AAD Groups for SharePoint permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

When using AAD groups within SharePoint permissions, if you add a user to that AAD group, how quickly does that permission change reflect in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it to be instant, or at least quick enough to be negligible.

When making the change in AD instead of AAD, you need to run `start-adsyncsynccycle -policytype delta` and wait for the sync to be complete.